# Can't bind to angular repository data with promise

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, repository, q

I'm trying to use the repository pattern with Angular. When I call my repository, I can see that the json is returned over the network. But I can't bind to it.

I'm injecting the repository into the module... what's wrong?

```
blogApp.factory('blogEntryRepository', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        get: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('/blogentry').success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.reject);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});


blogApp.controller("HomeCtrl", function($scope, blogEntryRepository) {
    blogEntryRepository.get().then($scope.blogEntries = blogEntryRepository);
});

<div>
    home  
    <div ng-repeat="blogEntry in blogEntries">
        <div>Asdf
            {{blogEntry.title}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The page outputs

```
home
Asdf
{}
```

The json response is

```
[{"title":"Launched an AngularJS 1.2 site!","date":"2014-05-21T00:00:00"},{"title":"Title2","date":"2014-05-22T00:00:00"}]
```

It's within an ng-app tag. There's an ng-view tag on the page.

I can confirm that I can bind to a hard coded variable.

Using Angular 1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
blogApp.controller("HomeCtrl", function($scope, blogEntryRepository) {
    blogEntryRepository.get().then(function(result){$scope.blogEntries = result});
});
```